# How to customize auto completing list in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, custom-attributes, autosuggest

I am intellij user. I am not sure this post is fits to stackoverflow or super user.

Recently, I am working on a project with customized language, which developed by co-workers. It is customized HTML.

However I want to add some words to suggestion list. i.e when I make a `div`, then I want to find `lang` attribute on auto suggestion list.

If you know how to customize auto completing suggestion, please reply!
Thanks in advanced!

//############ Edit ##################

I found it! when you type `div` and waiting, a bulb pop up appears.
There is where users can add custom suggestions.

However, I want to know where to store all this suggestions.
(So I can add several keywords at once!)

Comment: Add the word 'wibble' to the suggestions and search on the filesystem using find and grep to find a file with wibble in it. It may be in a directory called .idea within your project source, or it may be in the general configuration directory. Without knowing the specific version of intellij and the OS you're using it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. my intellij version is 14.1.5 and OS is OSX. I have already searched .idea folder but could not find any.